# Moving selected SlickGrid rows with arrow buttons

Tags: slickgrid

is it possible to move selected rows up and down using arrow keys? The drag and drop works great, but my project requires moving using a keyboard as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't figure out how to get it working but the source includes a `keydown` event so definitely this is possible. I'll let you know once I achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! If I figure it out, I'll post here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `enableCellNavigation: true` in the options object. If you inspect the cells with Firebug or the like you'll notice that the `active` class value moves along with your keyboard presses.

So the thing is to CSS-format `.active`, I'm not sure whether SlickGrid provides it it already.